# I have a sql server table like as follows below

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two cols like as follows below

```
ID  SAL
1   1000
2   2000
3   3000
4   4000
5   5000
```

### I'd like to have an output like that:

```
ID  SAL
1   1000
2   3000
3   6000
4   10000
5   15000
```

*/
How can we achieve this without using case statements ?

Comment: Your caps-lock key is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(SAL) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS SAL
FROM YourTable;
```

That's called running sum and works in `SQL Server 2012+`

An example for response:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID INT, SAL INT);

INSERT INTO @Test
    (ID, SAL)
VALUES
      (1, 1000)
    , (2, 2000)
    , (3, 3000)
    , (4, 4000)
    , (5, 5000);

SELECT ID, SUM(SAL) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS SAL
FROM @Test
```

**Resulted in:**

```
ID  SAL
----------
1   1000
2   3000
3   6000
4   10000
5   15000
```

Comment: Hi @Evaldas Buinauskas,
Hope you doing grate,

thanks for your replay, But for your query the out put as follows below

1 15000.00
2 15000.00
3 15000.00
4 15000.00
5 15000.00

once again go through the scenario, and get back with proper  Query.

Comment: @bharath I've just tried that by myself (see updated answer). I got correct and expected result.